# Make sense of webrtc dump

Tags: google-chrome, video, web, html5-video, webrtc

I downloaded the dump from **chrome://webrtc-internals**

now i want to make sense from this data and plot some graph as to show the packet loss and other stuffs which is included in the dump

I can see the graphs in **chrome://webrtc-internals** only , but i want to do this stuff by myself and in process also understand the logs better.

What does each field means

Till now i can only understand that it is a **json dump**.

please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The value arrays that you see under under each log item are the value that is gathered for that item for that second. So, for `values[0]` is the log information gathered for that  category for the first second. So, match the ssrc with the one provided in the SDPs to get each ssrc's log information for each second.

Explained further:

This shows that there is no packet lost for ssrc `1814250626` and shows that there was zero packet loss for each second for the log period.

```
"ssrc_1814250626-packetsLost": {
     "startTime": "2014-05-11T21:26:06.360Z",
     "endTime": "2014-05-11T21:26:19.362Z",
     "values": "[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
    },
```

We can compare the ssrc value against the SDPs that are exchanged to get who and what media type each source represents.

```
"time": "5/11/2014 4:26:05 PM",
     "type": "createOfferOnSuccess",
     "value": "type: offer, sdp: v=0\r\no=- 140296487447716144 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS yGvpzuQVRTY2AmSWclrFlBZctrOijzNQkLnN\r\nm=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Xv9/Bx9tAWEOh1pE\r\na=ice-pwd:e7rRuOyKLk1bKUcZ1S+tDw7r\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 B4:1F:B0:32:31:60:0F:E1:EC:6D:0E:65:1D:F8:F6:F1:0C:FE:D9:46:41:37:8A:7A:21:AC:39:7A:12:0E:12:99\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:gl34DLHmuMoKoaUWhYJpDJUFkZagn1cedT1x6nQh\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:1814250626 cname:aIdRfz6vBYDbJiEF\r\na=ssrc:1814250626 msid:yGvpzuQVRTY2AmSWclrFlBZctrOijzNQkLnN fad6fe24-b006-4a57-80d6-c603416f32b5\r\na=ssrc:1814250626 mslabel:yGvpzuQVRTY2AmSWclrFlBZctrOijzNQkLnN\r\na=ssrc:1814250626 label:fad6fe24-b006-4a57-80d6-c603416f32b5\r\nm=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Xv9/Bx9tAWEOh1pE\r\na=ice-pwd:e7rRuOyKLk1bKUcZ1S+tDw7r\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 B4:1F:B0:32:31:60:0F:E1:EC:6D:0E:65:1D:F8:F6:F1:0C:FE:D9:46:41:37:8A:7A:21:AC:39:7A:12:0E:12:99\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:video\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:gl34DLHmuMoKoaUWhYJpDJUFkZagn1cedT1x6nQh\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:116 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000\r\na=ssrc:477546681 cname:aIdRfz6vBYDbJiEF\r\na=ssrc:477546681 msid:yGvpzuQVRTY2AmSWclrFlBZctrOijzNQkLnN 6d5c1c40-6921-40d2-ba53-f413afb76ad1\r\na=ssrc:477546681 mslabel:yGvpzuQVRTY2AmSWclrFlBZctrOijzNQkLnN\r\na=ssrc:477546681 label:6d5c1c40-6921-40d2-ba53-f413afb76ad1\r\n"
    }
```

We can see from above that since it is an `createOfferOnSuccess` event, then we know that it is the local parties SDP. Following this we can see that local Audio is `ssrc:1814250626` and local video is `ssrc:477546681`. So, to get the stats on the local video, just grab each value array that begins with `ssrc_477546681`. It also gives you the log start time and end time in that same json object.

If they value stays the same in the value array (numerous of the same value):

```
"ssrc_477546681-googFrameHeightInput": {
     "startTime": "2014-05-11T21:26:06.360Z",
     "endTime": "2014-05-11T21:26:19.362Z",
     "values": "[480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480,480]"
    },
```

Then you can bet it did not change for each second during the log period.

Comment: but how do i detect packet loss?
and also can i plot the graph real time on same video chat , experimental?

Comment: @Rohit you grab the packet lost field from the dump and it shows you the packet loss for each second. Also, since it is a dump, it is not live data. You would have to work with chrome internals for that not just the dump

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xs2TNeVh
please help me make sense of this data
I am sorry for troubling but i am really new to webrtc and can't seem to find any tutorial on webrtc dump

Comment: Line 875 shows no packets were lost for ssrc:1742396484. From line 581 we see that ssrc:1742396484 is video and the local video ssrc of 192.168.1.102 (you can see from the ice gathering later in that section, line 641).

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

still one doubt , how do you map ssrc to element name.

Comment: @Rohit, what element name? How to tell if it is video? Or the piece of hardware giving the video? The party that is providing the video? You can match the google track ID with the SSRC as the track ID is mentioned in the SDP.

Answer (score 2):

Import the dump into this tool to get some useful interactive graphs :

https://fippo.github.io/webrtc-dump-importer/

edit: fixed url

Answer (score 1):

For better analysis of data you can use the testRTC tools made by webrtc team of google.
A simple demo that how to analyze the data is given in this link:
https://testrtc.com/docs/analyze-webrtc-dump/