# Monitor WebRTC video (media) stream quality in Javascript

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I'm using WebRTC to stream video between peers, but changes in network conditions for some clients often produce quality changes in the received video stream. People blame the service for these quality drops and clearly I (the service) cannot do anything about their network conditions. But showing an indication that the quality dropped due to network conditions on the client's end would most likely alleviate this problem.

I've been searching Google & Stackoverflow for a while now and haven't seen any questions related to quality detection of incoming audio or video stream. Is there a way to monitor the quality (current bitrate or dropped frames, anything) during the live stream?

Comment: If they are using Chrome, you can use `chrome://webrtc-internals/`. I answered a similar question on [how to read the data dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591225/make-sense-of-webrtc-dump/23598331#23598331) you grab from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [getStats()](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#dom-peerconnection-getstats) API is what you are looking for if you want to *programmatically* access information in real time. webrtc-internals is a separate webpage, that is providing you more informations than getstats because it has access to chrome internals, but eventually most of those info will be made available to getstats so people can have access to them from within their app.

Comment: Are there any recent examples of getStats()? I have been recently been playing around with it but the results do not match the expected behavior. The implementation also is different in chrome than the one from the link to getStats()

Comment: getStats is still in motion, so you should expect a difference between the specs and the implementations for the time being. This is the official example of getStats():
http://googlechrome.github.io/webrtc/samples/web/content/constraints/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webrtc-issue-detector](https://github.com/VLprojects/webrtc-issue-detector) to monitor the quality of webrtc session on the client side. It uses [getStats()](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-peerconnection-getstats) under the hood and identifies issues that may affect media quality like client CPU issues, network or server side issues.

Comment: Good open source library. I also use [webrtc-issue-detector](https://github.com/VLprojects/webrtc-issue-detector) TypeScript library on client side to calculate MOS (Mean Opinion Score) to show the connection / network quality (e.g. for warnings like "Your connection is not stable...")